# How to solve 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'encode'?

Tags: python-3.x, hdf5, h5py

Below is my code.

```
#Used to create the h5py file
import h5py
column_data=np.random.randint(low=5,high=23,size=(4,4))
row_data=[-1,1,1,-1]
db=h5py.File('penguin.hdf5',mode='w')
bhagavat=db.create_dataset('manu',shape=(4,5),dtype=float)
bhagavat[0:4] = np.c_[row_data, column_data]
db.close()

#This is to read the penguin.hdf5 file
db = h5py.File('penguin.hdf5', mode="r")
(labels, data) = (db[bhagavat][:, 0], db[bhagavat][:, 1:])
db.close()
```

The error i am getting while reading penguin.hdf5 file is shown below.

```
AttributeError: 'Dataset' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing below line of code.

```
(labels, data) = (db[bhagavat][:, 0], db[bhagavat][:, 1:])
```

with

```
(labels, data) =(db['manu'][...][:, 0], db['manu'][...][:, 1:])
```

solves the error.

Comment: what is the issue?